# R: How to plot the last row of a dataframe?

Tags: ggplot2

This must be very easy, but I cannot get a plot of the last/any row of a dataframe.

```
A = data.frame(a = rnorm(50), b = rnorm(50), c = rnorm(50))
barplot(A[nrow(A),1:3])
```

I get the error message:

```
Error in barplot.default(A[nrow(A), 1:3]) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

A solution using ggplot would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imported `ggplot2` library and the dataset you gave me. used the `tail` command to get only the last row. Then had to `melt()` the data to get it into the right format, then plotted in ggplot2

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshap2)
A = data.frame(a = rnorm(50), b = rnorm(50), c = rnorm(50))

A_tail <- tail(A, 1)

tailmelt <- melt(A_tail)


ggplot(data = tailmelt, aes( x = factor(variable), y = value, fill = variable ) ) +  
  geom_bar( stat = 'identity' )
```